# Exception when convert string to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In `with` statement:

```
WITH queryResult AS
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-12 ' + PARTIALDATE) 
    FROM 
        tableA 
    WHERE 
        ISDATE('2017-12-12 ' + PARTIALDATE) = 1
)
....
```

In this block, I will get exception:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

So I made some changes:

```
WITH subQueryResult AS
(
    SELECT 
        PARTIALDATE 
    FROM 
        tableA 
    WHERE 
        ISDATE('2017-12-12 ' + PARTIALDATE) = 1
),
queryResult AS
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-12 ' + PARTIALDATE) 
    FROM 
        subQueryResult
)
```

And it works!

But why?

Comment: What is the datatype of the PARTIALDATE? my guess is.. the second query guarantees that partialdate is a date as non date rows are excluded.. hence the convert works

Comment: @Harry varchar(100)

Comment: @Harry but in first SQL text, I have just the same where statement.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server **2012** or newer, you could check out the `TRY_CAST` / `TRY_CONVERT` commands - they return `NULL`, if something cannot be converted (instead of throwing an error)

Comment: I only get this error when the PartialDate is not suitable and ISDATE() clause is not used in the Select statement. So ithe first query seems to be quite OK for my test

Comment: I might be wrong about this.. but with CTE, it might be how and when the Where clause is evaluated..

Comment: @marc_s Awesome! but our client may be have to modify the compatibility level to adapt to TRY_CONVERT

Comment: @Harry That's the key point. In my opinion where clause will be evaluated before select list.

Comment: @Eralper It's hard to reproduce. But in my development environment, it can be reproduced stably.

Comment: I'm running on SQL Server 2017, may be as @Marc  mentioned the cause can be the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` does not do the filtering before the conversion takes place. Order of operations is guaranteed for a case statement. The following should work:

```
WITH queryResult AS
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ISDATE('2017-12-12 ' + PARTIALDATE) = 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-12-12 ' + PARTIALDATE) ELSE NULL END
    FROM 
        tableA 
    WHERE 
        ISDATE('2017-12-12 ' + PARTIALDATE) = 1
)
```